# How to get the over all rake test result in file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rake-task

I am running a rake task for the more number of operations.

```
 Eg: rake test:sample

Finished in 66.951185957 seconds.

1 tests, 256 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed

0.01 tests/s, 3.82 assertions/s
```

I want to store the overall final result of rake task such as number of tests passed/failed with file name, assertions,errors etc in a file like index.html will be generated for rspec tests in coverage/index.html. I am using Test::Unit in rake task.

Can any one tell me solution for it.

Comment: `rake test:sample > index.html` ?

Comment: @fl00r Thanks. But it is store the termial output in a file. Is there way to output results with tabular format with filename, error, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use ci_reporter gem to generate the reports. it will results in xml format.

[Link Here](https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the rspec's help `rspec --help` which gives you a lot of options when testing with rspec. Hope it helps.